# How do you open a remote sqlite database over http?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Is it possible to open an sqlite file over http? I only need to read the db, and was hoping I could do something like:

```
var dbFile:File = new File("http://10.1.1.50/project/db.sqlite");
sqlConnection.open(dbFile);
```

`Error #3125: Unable to open the database file.', details:'Connection closed.', operation:'open', detailID:'1001'`

My situation calls for several apps compiled for various devices to share this file, which is served locally via wamp.

Comment: SQLite is by design not a client/server database, so I don't think this will work...

Comment: oh right, so I will need to request and store a local copy in that case

Comment: or you could use something like MySQL or MS SQL which is designed to be served over a network?

Comment: Yeah, didn't you mention a WAMP server? Can't the information be exposed via that?

Comment: It could be... the only reason I have the wamp server is to serve the shared files to the ipads etc - instead of embedding the file with the application (the current solution that makes infrequent updates a pain). I don't really have time to re implement the way the data is stored at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zip your sqlite file from **db.sqlite** to **db.zip**. Load this zip file in flex using URLLoader and [unzip it back in flex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ByteArrays_3.html).

If not, you can also rename the file's extension to .xml, load it using httpservice or urlloader and once you get the result, you can rename the file's name back to .sqlite and start querying the file and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can achieve this over HTTP.
SqLite is a file and not a service/process that may be accessible via any port.

The best case scenario is when you have network access to the computer where the sqlite file is stored, like:

```
\\myserver\databases\mysqlitefile.db
```

...but this may work only on windows :(

Comment: connections via \\myserver\data\... sometimes will not (always?) work. If you attach your network share to a drive letter S:\data\.. you will not have a problem normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your code to use modsqlite http://modsqlite.sourceforge.net/#using

Answer (score 0):

there's an apache module to allow remote sqlite access via http.

http://modsqlite.sourceforge.net/