# Can i use sqllite Database with Flex web application?

Tags: sqlite, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5

I am trying to create a Flex web application that can store the data in sqllite Database.

Can any one help me that how can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "exchange"? Web apps can use the DB to store their own data.

Comment: Sorry to use word "exchange" , my Question is how a Flex web app can store data in sqllite Database?

Answer (score 0):

From Flex web application you can interact with any Database, not only SQLite. 
But this can't be done directly. You need to use a server that will accept request from your app and store data in Database.

There is discussion on Adobe forums already.
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/501997

You can try to store the SQLite Database on your server and every time you need to update it download the database inside the app. And after update upload it back.

There is a good solution in this topic:
[How do you open a remote sqlite database over http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973659/how-do-you-open-a-remote-sqlite-database-over-http)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, flex can interact with any DB if using blazeds/java srvice/.net/php layer in between, if the DB is in the server. Flex web app cannot interact with any DB directly.

Because you are asking for sqllite, flex cannot create the sqllite on the client as it will be come the security sandbox violation. You can only do it with Adobe air framework, direct interaction with the sql db.

Answer (score 0):

If your db is hosted on server side, you can connect flex to the database use server side technologies.

If you want a db on client side. you may take a look at [here](http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/). As Flex can interact with js through ExternalInterface, you may access the local database from Flex